# Is there an API for jQuery unobtrusive validation?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-validate, unobtrusive-validation

I have this validation summary in my code:

```
@Html.ValidationSummary(false, "Fix Error", new { id = "valSumId" } )
```

Is there an API so I can add validation error during runtime? Though the following code works, it feels brittle, there's nothing to stop ASP.NET MVC team from not using ul li tags for displaying errors on the next ASP.NET MVC release.

```
$('input[type=submit]').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if ($('form').valid()) {
        /* ajax submit here */

        if (anErrorOccured) {
            $('#valSumId').removeClass().addClass('validation-summary-errors');
            errorList = $('#valSumId > ul');

                    // the message is variable, coming from JSON, and can be a list
            errorList.append($('<li />').text('Your ordered quantity is above the stock level'));
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: could you please explain (for me) ;) what you want... a diffent output of validation error messages or ... ?

Comment: Different output coming from server, anything that could fail saving of record, prior(e.g. business logic) or after it(e.g. Exceptions like concurrent update, duplicate error, etc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I wanted to achieve (see the jQuery code at the bottom): http://www.ienablemuch.com/2011/07/ivalidatableobject-client-side.html

For now, while I still don't know the API for inserting the errors to client-side validation, hardcoding them with ul li would be fine. I already made a nice wrapper around what I wanted to achieve, so in any point in the future I discover the jQuery validation API, the program is insulated to the code changes needed be made.

Answer (score 0):

No, there isn't.  The approach you outline does not belong on the client side.  Messages like "Your ordered quantity is above the stock level" should really come from the server.  You can set up validations like that with remote validation or server side validation, both of which would feed into the validation summary without a need to manually add them.

Comment: Yeah I know it doesn't belong in client, in fact I outlined that in my question, after saving record via Ajax, my code will receive JSON from MVC's JsonResult. That JSON could contain server-side business logic message, exceptions caught like concurrent update, any constraints that was forgot to placed in Model, server disk full, etc :-)

Comment: I like Remote validation(via Remote attribute), but it could not catch model-level validations, and any db-level constraints(anything that happens after saving)

Comment: That makes sense.  What I was thinking was that instead of returning JSON, just render the view with the form and the model state errors would be populated.

Comment: Already exercised that approach. I want something ajax-y, I could use Ajax.BeginForm(), but it also carries post's payload, the View, i.e. the html of all controls. Just interested with the messages emitted by the server and render it a future-proof manner. Cannot guarantee future-proofness on my code above, I rely too much on tags I gleaned from FireBug, I hardcoded ul and li tag. If there's a way to append message on message summary without relying too much on those tags(ul li), it would be better.